# Wake on lan not working on any PC. Could it be the router?

Tags: networking, router

I work from home doing PC & laptop repairs and have several PC's in my workshop and in the house that I can wake up remotely, or at least I used to be able to.  In short, I've tried several different wake on lan programs on several different PC's and none of them are working on any of my PC's.  My preferred program is Nirsoft's WakemeonLan as it has a nice easy interface that lists all the devices by name, MAC address & IP address.   Can anyone suggest a reason why they would all suddenly stop waking up?  The only thing I can think of is the router, which is a virgin superhub.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks,  Alan

Comment: Please explain your network setup. It can’t be a router if all the computers are connected to the same network subnet. There is a well known limitation on WOL that you need to use the MAC addresss of the remote machine for your target. Trying to use a DNS name or IP address will fail because the remote computer retains neither of those things while sleeping.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  A fairly normal setup really.  Virgin superhub connected via cat5 to another superhub in my workshop which has DHCP off and is reconfigured as an access point).  two pc's are connected to the access point & several others via a switch. The mac addresses  pc's listed correctly in the WOL software.  They all worked fine until recently, but for some reason, none of them do now,  I had some broadband problems recently and was wondering if any of the tests or updates to the router may have caused the problem.